# How to verify dSYMs are uploaded to Crashlytics

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I use Fabric Crashlytics. They recently deprecated uploading dSYMs over the web interface. I have the build phase setup and it seems to work fine.

Still, I'm a bit anxious every time I publish a new build as one can't be 100% sure the dSYMs got uploaded correctly until there is a crash. And I don't know of an easy way of causing a crash in a production build (if I did I would have fixed it).

I know I'd get a "missing dSYMs" warning if there was a crash. But as far as I know, I can't get an email notification about that (can I?) - so, I'd not know about that crash unless I check the console every day.

Is there a way to list the uploaded dSYMs or verify that Crashlytics has dSYMs for build XY?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make sure the dSYM is available or not for the particular build by verifying it in the below tabs

> itunesConnect/MyApps/yourApp/Activity tab/your build version

Please find the image below for your reference

[image: reference]

Comment: Well, this is dSYMs in iTunes connect. Not in Crashlytics. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes that's for apple store, but in the fabric, they will give an alert in the dashboard if dym is missing but the point is: In the build phase, you can setup the run script using the api key and build secret, it will take care of uploading the dSYM automatically, we dont need to upload it manually.